# Short method for echo in HTML-document?

Tags: php, html, echo

Is there a shorter way to echo a variable within a html script

for example: index.php

```
...
<head><title><?php echo $MyTitle; ?></title></head>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is

```
<?= $MyTitle ?>
```

But it can be disabled in some php configurations wich is defined in your php.ini as `short-open-tag`
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Also, __Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.__